# Reach Router Link in Gatsby flashes page then disappears

Tags: gatsby, client-side, reach-router

I'm using Reach Router in Gatsby to set up client-side routing as below, but when I click the link to my About page, it flashes the content from my About component and then disappears.

```
import React from "react"
import { Router, Link } from "@reach/router"

import About from "../components/about.js"
import Layout from "../components/layout"

const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Link to="about">About</Link>
    <Router>
      <MapContainer path="/" />
      <About path="/about" />
    </Router>
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage
```

I've also found that when I `import { Link } from 'gatsby'` instead of `import { Link } from '@reach/router'`, it takes me straight to Gatsby's 404 page.

In both cases, the back button on my browser brings me back to the homepage (displaying MapContainer), which I think means that the link is trying to find a static page that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Gatsby's routing extends from React routing so you don't need to import it from React. Gatsby's has the same behavior plus some other features.

As you pointed out, you should use `<Link>` from Gatsby rather than `@reach/router`. Your issue comes from the path of the link, since you posted as an absolute it leads to a `404` page. It should look like:

```
import React from "react"
import {Link} from 'gatsby'
import About from "../components/about.js"
import Layout from "../components/layout"

const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Link to="/about">About</Link>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage
```

Note the relative paths (starting with a trailing slash, `/`) and the Router removal since it's redundant.

You can check for further information in [Gatsby's Link API documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-link/) and [Linking between pages documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/linking-between-pages/).